# Calling functions in a second file when compiling .Rmd files with knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I want to use `knitr` to format an R markdown file, lets call it `Main.rmd`. Some code in `Main.rmd` relies on helper functions in a second file, lets call it `Functions.rmd`.
When I first run `Functions.rmd` and then `Main.rmd`, the code in `Main.rmd` runs fine. When I first run `Functions.rmd` and then try to knit `Main.rmd`, I receive an evaluation:

> Error "Object 'myfunction' not found

How can I fix this without combining `Main.rmd` and `Functions.rmd` into a single document, which I would like to avoid doing?

Edit: I've added a toy example below. There are very useful suggestions so far for how to call the functions in `Functions.rmd` from `Main.rmd`, but they all require converting `Functions.rmd` to a .R file. However, for my current purpose, it is important that `Functions.rmd` can also be read as a standalone markdown document.

First, `Main.rmd`:

````
---
title: "Main_test"
author: "Matt Nolan"
date: "25/06/2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Background.
This is the main body of text and code used to display results of analyses, some of which are created by calling functions in Functions.Rmd.

```{r cars}
myexamplefunction(1,2)
```
````

And, here is `Functions.rmd`:

````
---
title: "Functions_test"
author: "Matt Nolan"
date: "25/06/2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Background
This is a document containing functions used in the document "Main_test". 
Because it contains functions and formatted text to explain the functions for an interested reader, it should be usable as a standalone markdown document.

For example, this is a function that adds two numbers.
```{r cars}
myexamplefunction <- function(a, b) {a + b}
```
````

Comment: `Main.rmd` will not look in your global environment for anything created by `Functions.rmd`. Rmd files are run in their own clean environment when knitted. You need to have some code in your `Main.rmd` that actually loads `Functions.rmd` into the same environment. For instance, if it was just a .R file, then `Main.rmd` could just `source` it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 30Jun2018 Update: R Markdown does not support combining Rmd files

Matt's 25Jun2018 update clarifies the question, asking how to embed one Rmd document in another Rmd document. Per the [R Markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/gallery.html) website, R Markdown requires **a single** Rmd file. It does not currently support the embedding of one Rmd file within another Rmd document.

[image]

That said, with the `bookdown` package, you could structure the Rmd files as chapters in a book, where each Rmd file is a chapter in the book. For details, see *Bookdown: Authoring Books with R Markdown* [1.4 - Two Rendering Approaches](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html), the [Getting Started](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/get-started.html) page, and the [Bookdown Demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) github repository for an example book built in `bookdown`.

## 25Jun2018 Update: Printing the code in an Appendix

Per the comments from the OP, the reason for including the functions in an Rmd file instead of an R file was to obtain a formatted printout of the code in an Appendix. This is possible with the technique I originally posted plus a few changes.

1. Use named chunks to put the code in an appendix, and use the arguments `echo=TRUE` and `eval=FALSE` to avoid executing it multiple times.
2. Execute code from the Appendix in main flow of the document by way of the `ref.label=` argument, and keep the code from printing in the main document with the `echo=FALSE` argument.
3. In addition to using the `source()` function, one must print each function in another chunk in the appendix in order to obtain formatted print of each function.

An updated version of my example Rmd file is listed below.

````
---
title: "TestIncludedFiles"
author: "Len Greski"
date: "June 24, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Background

A question was posted on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013924/calling-functions-in-a-second-file-when-compiling-rmd-files-with-knitr) about how to include functions from one Rmd file while knitting another. 

If the second file contains R functions to be accessed in the second Rmd file, they're best included as R files rather than Rmd. In this example we'll include three files of functions from the Johns Hopkins University *R Programming* course: `pollutantmean()`, `corr()`, and `complete()`. We'll execute them in a subsequent code block. 

After an update to the original post where the original poster noted that he included the functions in an Rmd file in order to provide a formatted printout of the code in the report as an appendix, I've modified this example to account for this additional requirement. 

```{r ref.label="sourceCode",echo=FALSE}
 # execute sourceCode chunk from appendix 
```

## Executing the sourced files

Now that the required R functions have been sourced, we'll execute them.


```{r runCode, echo=TRUE}
pollutantmean("specdata","nitrate",70:72)
complete("specdata",1:10)
corr("specdata",threshold=500)
```

# Appendix 


```{r sourceCode,echo=FALSE,eval=FALSE}
# use source() function to source the functions we want to execute
source("./rprogramming/oneLine_pollutantmean.r")
source("./rprogramming/oneLine_complete.r")
source("./rprogramming/oneLine_corr.r")
```

The following is an inventory of the functions used in this Rmd file.

```{r }
pollutantmean
complete
corr
```
````

...and the output for the Appendix section of the document (with redactions to avoid publishing answers to a class programming assignment).

[image]

## Original Answer

If the second Rmd file only contains functions, you're better off saving them as an R file and using `source()` to include them in `Main.Rmd`. For example:

````
date: "June 24, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Background

A question was posted on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013924/calling-functions-in-a-second-file-when-compiling-rmd-files-with-knitr) about how to include functions from one Rmd file while knitting another. 

If the second file contains R functions to be accessed in the second Rmd file, they're best included as R files rather than Rmd. In this example we'll include three files of functions from the Johns Hopkins University *R Programming* course: `pollutantmean()`, `corr()`, and `complete()`. We'll execute them in a subsequent code block. 

```{r sourceCode,echo=TRUE}
# use source() function to source the functions we want to execute
source("./rprogramming/pollutantmean.r")
source("./rprogramming/complete.r")
source("./rprogramming/corr.r")
```

## Executing the sourced files

Now that the required R functions have been sourced, we'll execute them.


```{r runCode, echo=TRUE}
pollutantmean("specdata","nitrate",70:72)
complete("specdata",1:10)
corr("specdata",threshold=500)
```
````

...produces the following output:

[image]

**DISCLOSURE:** This answer includes techniques that I previously posted as a blog article in 2016, [ToothGrowth Assignment: Accessing R Code from an Appendix in Knitr](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/statinf-accessingRCodeFromKnitrAppendix.md).

Comment: Hi Len, thanks for the answer. This is useful and works. However, I want the functions in "Functions.Rmd" to be made available as a formatted appendix to "Main.Rmd", and so, in this case, I want the functions to remain in a separate markdown document. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hello Matt. Yes, you can include the code as a named chunk in the Appendix, render the code with `echo=TRUE` and prevent it from executing with `eval=FALSE` options. I have a blog article that explains exactly how to do this, but I'll need edit my answer to include sample code to illustrate it given SO's policy of providing answers that don't direct people off the site. I'll try to get to this within the next 24 hours.

Comment: @MattNolan - updated answer, decided to take care of it before heading into the office this morning.

Comment: many thanks for that Len. It is again very useful, but not quite what I'm trying to do. I've edited the main question with additional clarification.

Comment: @MattNolan - updated my answer, R Markdown does not support the feature you require, but the `bookdown` package does.

Comment: Brilliant, that does what I need (and more). Thanks.

Comment: @MattNolan - you're welcome. The additional detail you added to your question made it clear why you want to use 2 Rmd files, which led me to confirm the one file limitation in R Markdown and post the alternate `bookdown` solution.  I was already aware of `bookdown`, but the simplest answer for your original question without the added context is to source R scripts in an Appendix.